# Server CPU reaching 100% with less than 50 users on website (Drupal 6)

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-6

I am having trouble with a website I'm working with that was developed with Drupal 6 and that behaves in a weird way.

The problem is that with **less than 50 users the CPU usage of the server reaches 100%** (today it happened at a peak of 40 users). It used to be worse, with the server crashing and the site being down as a consequence but now it's just slow. Maybe it would crash again if we had 100 users instead of 50.

**Here is the server configuration :**

**CPU**
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E6550 @ 2.33GHz
Cache : 4096KB
**RAM**
2x 2048Mo
**Drives:** 
2 x 750 Go

Somehow, I feel like having 50 users on this website is similar to having 500 on a well optimised website. Like if the drupal website was multiplying the number of useless queries, making the website so slow. The number of request per minute is 3300 despite a generally low number of users on the website (maximum simultaneous connections: 35).

I used mysqltuner, here is the file with the recommendation might it be useful :

> -------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
>   General recommendations:
>       Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
>       MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
>       Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
>       Reduce or eliminate persistent connections to reduce connection usage
>       Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
>       When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
>       Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
>       Set thread_cache_size to 4 as a starting value
>       Increase table_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
>       Read this before increasing table_cache over 64: http://bit.ly/1mi7c4C
>
> Variables to adjust:
>
> ```
> wait_timeout (< 28800)
> interactive_timeout (< 28800)
> query_cache_size (>= 8M)
> join_buffer_size (> 128.0K, or always use indexes with joins)
> tmp_table_size (> 32M)
> max_heap_table_size (> 16M)
> thread_cache_size (start at 4)
> table_cache (> )
> ```

I am aware that you might need more information to find out what might be wrong in the configuration. Please ask me what is needed, I will gladly edit my message to provide whatever information you consider relevant.

Answer (score 1):

50 concurrent users is plenty.  50/second means over 4 million a day.

There are tons of performance tricks you can apply

- apc
- memcached
- caching anonymous traffic (try varnish)
- caching blocks and authenticated users (search for modules and tricks for auth cache, views cache on drupal.org etc)
- database improvement

and many more..

Answer (score 1):

optimize from front end to back end

- front end optimization:
- Go to Drupal configuration performance and Do something in Caching
  section and Bandwidth optimization section
- use css spirits to decrease image HTTP request
- use drupal image module to adjust right size of your image
  use right cache in your browser(need to configure your web server)

back end optimization:
web server optimization and others you can see answer 1.